# How to get AIC, BIC for fitted lee carter in demography package in R?

Tags: r

I have trouble finding BIC and AIC values for lee carter that I fitted using lca command in demography package, 
This is how I fitted the model:

```
UKLcaM<-lca(data=UK, series="male", years=1950:2011, max.age=100,
adjust = "dxt", chooseperiod=FALSE, scale = TRUE,
restype = "logrates", interpolate = FALSE)
```

Can anyone help? BIC() command does give following errors

```
> BIC(UKLcaM)

Error in UseMethod("logLik") :    no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "lca"
```

Comment: Please include the error/log output. Would be helpful to know.

Comment: `AIC`, `BIC`, and `logLik` are generics that only work if the authors of the package have included methods for them. [this page](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/10379_1a1858a1259b4c019fb1092922e307b3.html) shows how to get the AIC for an `fdm` object but not `lca`. you can get the deviance with `UKLcaM$mdev`, but I haven't used this technique so I cant be any more help sorry